# Unable to run docker image on Windows desktop. Do I need different images if I want to run the images on windows and Linux

Tags: docker

When I run my docker image, I get error as the image can't find a file which should be there.

Error

```
C:\Users\..\web>docker run mmy-app-1.0-snapshot:latest
Oops, cannot start the server.
ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.JoranException: Could not open URL [file:/deploy/my-app-1.0/logback_prod.xml].
```

My local machine is a `windows 10` on which I want to test my `docker` image. Eventually, I'll install it on a virtual machine on `google` cloud. The image is of my `play framework` application which needs only `java` runtime only as per this document - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Deploying

The distribution of the application will have two files in the zip, one for `linux` and other a `.bat` file for windows. I want to be able to run the `linux` version on my windows machine by using `docker run`. For this I plan to create a docker image of my application.

Question 1) Can I use `Docker` to create such an image which I can run both on my windows machine and on a `linux` machine in the cloud?
Question 2) Will I need to create two separate images for `linux` and `windows`?

I have installed `docker desktop for windows` from https://hub.docker.com/?overlay=onboarding. I have created the following `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM openjdk:8
ENV APP_NAME      my-app
ENV APP_VERSION   1.0-SNAPSHOT
#make a directory deploy in the container
RUN mkdir deploy
#cd to container
WORKDIR deploy
#copy from host (path relative to location of Dockerfile on host) to deploy directory. The deploy directory will have my-app-1.0.zip, logback_prod.xml and application_prod.xml
COPY target/universal/my-app-1.0.zip .
COPY conf/logback_prod.xml .
COPY conf/application_prod.conf .
#unzip deploy/my-app-1.0.zip in container
RUN unzip my-app-1.0.zip
#chmod my-app script in deploy/my-app-1.0/bin/my-app
RUN chmod +x my-app-1.0/bin/my-app
#entrypoint is deploy/....
ENTRYPOINT my-app-1.0/bin/codingjediweb -Dplay.http.secret.key=changemeplease -Dlogger.file=logback_prod.xml -Dconfig.file=application_prod.conf
```

The `dockerfile` is at path `web` on my windows laptop. The same level has `conf` and `target` directories. I suppose in `Dockerfile` the `WORKDIR` is the path in the `image` and when I use `COPY` command, the first path (source) is the local path on my machine and the 2nd path (target) is the path in the image.

Question 3) when I run `docker run my-app-1.0-snapshot:latest`, I get the error stated at the beginning of the question. Why is the file not found? I notice the `url` is `/deploy/....`. As I had set the `WORKDIR` to `.`, shouldn't it be `./deploy`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that in `ENTRYPOINT`, I needed to specify the correct path - ENTRYPOINT my-app-1.0/bin/codingjediweb -Dplay.http.secret.key=changemeplease -Dlogger.file=deploy/logback_prod.xml -Dconfig.file=deploy/application_prod.conf

The WORKDIR is not used in -Dlogger.file and -Dconfig.file parameters it seems.